# Why the Google Data Highlighter for products isn't showing in Google?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo, rich-snippets, structured-data

I have a few sites that make it difficult for me to go in and implement structured data by code - Thus I revert to **using Google's Data Highlighter in Search Console.**

I have marked up two sites to test the results with - Google recognises the "Product" data added, no errors, but even after a whole month, **the prices rich snippet doesn't appear.**

I am wondering if anyone has had **any experience working with this tool** and **why Google hasn't shown me any rich snippets yet** - The sites I work with are well known local brands, sell a ton of products, and receive plenty of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Data Highlighter doesn't actually modify the HTML of the pages you use the tool on.

The tool gives you rendered HTML which you then need to add to your page.

In short: There is no way to add structured data to your websites without actually modifying the html.

If you did already modify the HTML of your pages, the structured data might still not show up in the search results. This has to do with many different factors, like trust of the website, trust of the page, age of the page etc.

**Edit:**

Actually on second look it seems that you don't need to modify the HTML when using the new data highlighter. Not sure why it doesn't work, but it might have to do with the points I mentioned above.

Some times that data appears, and some times it doesn't. Depends on page trust, age and also on the search query. Besides that it also depends on the Google version you are using. For some languages these snippets appear more often than for other languages.

**Edit 2:**

A couple of things you can try to see if the snippets appear:

- Try to use an incognito browser window. Some times the snippets are displayed when searching a query for the first time
- Try using a VPN to spoof your location around the world
- Use a different Google search language (for example google.co.uk or google.de, and choose the option to display it in the native language)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I don't think that's correct. Google says "You simply use Data Highlighter to tag the data fields on your site with a mouse. Then Google can present your data more attractively -- and in new ways -- in search results and in other products such as the Google Knowledge Graph." - Please validate.

Comment: Hi Edgar, yes that's right. Please see the edited answer. I noticed that you don't need to edit the HTML indeed when using the new data highlighter. The old version did require this though.

Comment: Ok I see you updated your post, thanks! I have tried everything you've said except using VPN and a different Google search language, the site targets Colombia, therefore I only care for google.com.co SERPs. Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: My pleasure! One thing I did notice when doing this myself for our website: In the beginning it didn't display the snippets at all, then after a while it was displayed some times, and now it's always displayed (after several months).

Comment: Try to add as much information as possible, like the in stock attribute, breadcrumbs, price, brand etc. I suspect the more information is available, the more chance google will show the snippets. Also I think positive reviews and links from high authority domains will work well to boost your site authority.

Comment: We've experienced similar issues, except we are implementing rich snippets via json+ld, so, in short, we are echoing out the attributes into a json array. The odd part is that some of the attributes have taken (mostly from the organization type and the category type), while the product-specific snippets are not being picked up by Google. Everything validates perfectly, however, in the testing tool.

Comment: Have you also defined the priceCurrency and the inStock attributes? I have messed around with it for a while also, and eventually ended up adding as many attributes as possible.

Comment: I've added only what Google Data Highlighter allows me to add, as in this particular project it is difficult to go in and make changes/additions to the site.